# pytest finds no tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I checked this issue on multiple posts and I think I have all the requirements met but pytest still finds no tests.

My test class is called test_login.py

Its contents are:

```
class TestLogin:

    def test_login_success(self, driver, messages, log):
        login = LoginPage(driver)
        login.enter_email("Mark")
        login.enter_password("Passw0rd")
        login.click_login()
        log.info("Login clicked")

        assert messages['login_page_title'] == driver.title, \
            f"Expected: {messages['login_page_title']}\nActual: {driver.title}"
```

I run it from the root directory that has a pytest.ini with the following contents:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --strict-markers -v
markers =
    feature: Deep validation of the application
```

and a conftest.py with the fixtures used in the test defined.
Every directory in the project has an `__init__.py` file

When I run the test I get:

```
================================================================ test session starts ================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-5.2.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0 -- /Users/mark/Python_Auto_Framework/com/companyname/venv/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/mark/Python_Auto_Framework, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: testrail-e2e-2.0.0, xdist-1.30.0, bdd-3.2.1, forked-1.1.1, docker-compose-3.2.0, cov-2.8.1
collected 0 items                                                                                                                                   

=============================================================== no tests ran in 0.04s ===============================================================
```

When I try to run the test by directly referencing it like so:

```
pytest com/companyname/Tests/test_login.py::test_login_success
```

I get:

```
================================================================ test session starts ================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-5.2.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0 -- /Users/mark/Python_Auto_Framework/com/companyname/venv/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/mark/Python_Auto_Framework, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: testrail-e2e-2.0.0, xdist-1.30.0, bdd-3.2.1, forked-1.1.1, docker-compose-3.2.0, cov-2.8.1
collected 0 items                                                                                                                                   

=============================================================== no tests ran in 0.02s ===============================================================
ERROR: not found: 
/Users/mark/Python_Auto_Framework/com/companyname/Tests/test_login.py::test_login_success
(no name '/Users/mark/Python_Auto_Framework/com/companyname/Tests/test_login.py::test_login_success' in any of [<Module test_login.py>])
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Update:
I ran with --debug and looked in the pytestdebug file and I saw the following:

```
matched test file 
'/Users/mark/Python_Auto_Framework/com/companyname/Tests/test_login.py' 
[assertion]
      found cached rewritten pyc for '/Users/mark/Python_Auto_Framework/com/companyname/Tests/test_login.py' [assertion]
      early skip of rewriting module: Pages [assertion]
      early skip of rewriting module: Pages.LoginPage [assertion]
      early skip of rewriting module: Core [assertion]
      early skip of rewriting module: Core.Utils [assertion]
```

But a recursive find on all dirs for the compiled copy shows nothing

[image]

Comment: If you reference the test directly, you also have to add the test class, e.g. `test_login.py::TestLogin::test_login_success`.

Comment: ERROR: not found: /Users/markdevine/IdeaProjects/Python_Auto_Framework/com/companyname/Tests/test_login.py::TestLogin::test_login_success
(no name '/Users/mark/Python_Auto_Framework/com/companyname/Tests/test_login.py::TestLogin::test_login_success' in any of [<Module test_login.py>])

Comment: Try to run `python -m pytest` from the root path of your project (not sure which it is).

Comment: python -m pytest also finds no tests

Comment: Can you retry be renaming your test directory from  `Test` to `test`? And, make sure this directory contains `__init__.py`.

Comment: test directory renamed to tests. No joy. Test directory renamed to test. No joy. Every directory in the project has an ````__init__.py````.  Could there be something cached?

Comment: There shouldn't be something cached. Can you show your directory layout?

Comment: dir structure added

Comment: I'd suggest rename `test` to `tests` and rename `TestSuit` directory to a name such that there is no `test` in its name.

Comment: renamed test to tests, renamed TestSuite to suites, renamed every other directory to be all lower case names

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem... Do I understand that correctly: your root path is `com`, and you start pytest from there? And if you do `pytest companyname/Tests/test_login.py::TestLogin::test_login_success`, you get the error?

Comment: root directory is not com

Comment: My final thought: cd into `companyname` and enter `pytest tests`. Namely, the test directory must be present in the path from which you issue the command: `pytest tests` [tests being the directory name for your tests]

Comment: cded into companyname and ran pytest tests. no joy

Comment: Your `pytest.ini` and `config.py` are both in `com`, so what is your root dir if not this?

Comment: they are not both in com. They are both in Python_Auto_Framework which is the root of the project. com is also in Python_Auto_Framework

Comment: Wild guess: one of the plugins is messing things up. Try creating a fresh venv aside the existing one: `python3.8 -m venv2 && source venv2/bin/activate && pip install pytest && pytest`, does the error persist?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding *pytest.ini* file in root directory and add directory names (which contains your testcases) to testpaths. Below is example:

**pytest.ini**

```
[pytest]
testpaths = Tests
```

Comment: I had pytest.ini in the root directory. I added testpaths with the path to tests (testpaths = com/companyname/Tests) and without (testpaths = Tests). Neither worked

Comment: looks like your testcases are under directory `tests`. Add the  `testpaths = tests` in `pytest.ini` file. It should work

Comment: I always update the ini when I updated as per the comments. No joy